# How to print values dynamically in Flask web app?

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I am using following code to display camera feed in Flask web app.

**App.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


def gen_frames():
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')  # concat frame one by one and show result


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**templates/index.html**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" width="50%">
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to print frame[0][0][0] value dynamically using commas at the bottom of the video like below.

**Video Feed**

51, 37, 222, 67, ...

Could you please help me with that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: browser loads frames automatically without using any JavaScript code, and it gets already converted to JPG - so it doesn't have direct access to original frame. You may need to use JavaScript which runs loop to get JPG image and expected data from sever and put image in src as string base64, and display value below image

Comment: eventually you could run loop wiith JavaScript which get only `frame[0][0][0]` from server - but you would have to keep frame in Python in global variable to have access from other functions in Python. But this may get new value `frame[0][0][0]` when browser still display previous `frame`

Comment: the most complex method is to get image from `src=` and put on `Canvas` to uncompress from JPG to normal data and get value from this canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to run JavaScript code with loop which periodically gest this value from server and put value in `HTML`.

But `frame` has to be in global variable to access it in another function in flask. And after converting frame to `jpg` you have to use different variable for this value.

But this method sometimes may have problem with synchromization. It may get value from new `frame` but browser may still display old `frame`.

---

Minimal working code

It uses `setInterval(function, 40)` to run function every 40ms (which gives 25 executions per second - like 25 frames per second). And this function uses `fetch()` to get value (JSON) from url `/get_value` and display it in `<div id="value">`

**EDIT:** I use `frame[0,0,0].tolist()` instead of `frame[0,0].tolist()` to get only `BLUE` (cv2 keeps pixel as `B,G,R` instead of `R,G,B`). I also add all values to `innerText` instead of repalcing previous value.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, jsonify, Response
import cv2
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#success, frame = camera.read()  # default value at start
success = False  # default value at start
frame   = None   # default value at start


def gen_frames():
    global success
    global frame
    
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            image = buffer.tobytes()   # use other variable instead of `frame`
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n'
                   b'\r\n' + image + b'\r\n')  # concat frame one by one and show result
            time.sleep(0.04) # my `Firefox` needs this to have time to display image.
                             # And this gives stream with 25 FPS (Frames Per Second) (1s/0.04s = 25)

@app.route('/get_value')
def get_value():
    #if frame is not None:
    if success:
        value = frame[0,0,2].tolist()
    else:
        value = ['?']
        
    #print(value)
    return jsonify(value)        


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" width="50%">
    </div>
    <div id="value"></div>
    
<script>
place = document.querySelector("#value");

setInterval(function(){
    console.log("run function");
    fetch("/get_value")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if(place.innerText.length > 0){
            place.innerText += ",";
        }
        place.innerText += data;
    })
}, 40);
</script
    
</body>
''')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app.run(debug=True) #, use_reloader=False)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stopped by `Ctrl+C`")
    finally:
        camera.release()
```

Comment: thank you for the great answer. But I need the blue value of the first pixel. frame[0][0][0]. Values should be populated with a comma. Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please print that value in down direction. No need comma thing if it is impossible.

Comment: if you need one value then get `blue = frame[0,0,0]` instead `frame[0,0].tolist()` and send it as list `[blue]` and in JavaScript display `data[0]` instead of `data`.

Comment: to append text you can use `.insert("," + data[0])` or `place.innerText = place.innerText + "," + data[0]`. It may need also to check length of `place.innerText` to skip `,` before first element.

Comment: I added modifications to code.